# (ROS) Failed to create global planner

Tags: c++, ubuntu-18.04, ros

My setup is: ROS melodic, Ubuntu: 18.04

I want simulate turtlebot3 moving with my own global planner and have been following this tutorial to get started: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS#Running_the_Plugin_on_the_Turtlebot. The tutorial seem to be made for ROS hydro, but as it was the best source of guidance I could find I hoped it would work.

The error I'm having is:

```
Failed to create the global_planner/GlobalPlanner planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type global_planner::GlobalPlanner as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
```

To my knowledge I've followed the tutorial as much as possible with a only a few things done differently because I wanted to test it, couldn't do as the tutorial asked, or because I thought it wouldn't impact the results. What I have done differently is:

1. I use the carrot_planner.h and carrot_planner.cpp files in the tutorial section 1 to test that it works before trying with my own code to avoid confusion about where possible errors come from. It's not 'different' from the tutorial to my knowledge, but figured I'd mention it. They are placed in catkin_ws/src/carrot_planner/src/global_planner/
2. The ros package I'm working from is in catkin_ws/src and is called the carrot_planner. In the tutorial step 1.3 I use add_library(global_planner_lib src/global_planner/carrot_planner.cpp). Would not imagine it affects the results either.
3. In section 3 of the tutorial it mentions that *'First, you need to copy the package that contains your global planner (in our case global_planner) into the catkin workspace of your Turtlebot (e.g. catkin_ws).'* Since my package was already in catkin_ws/src/ I haven't moved it since I guess I didn't need to.
4. I've altered the 'move_base.launch' file in '/opt/ros/melodic/share/turtlebot3_navigation/launch/' instead of the 'move_base.launch.xml' in '/opt/ros/hydro/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/' as there doesn't seem to be a destination '...turtlebot3_navigation/launch/includes/'. There are files in launch, but no includes folder. Maybe that a difference from Hydro to Melodic, I don't know. There may be a whole lot of things that need to be done differently from the tutorial when using Melodic, or with turtlebot3, but I don't know.
5. I haven't made my own launch file for bringup of the turtlebot, but have instead followed this tutorial (https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/nav_simulation/) to guide me with turtlebot3. After finishing this step in the global planner tutorial **'Save and close the move_base.launch.xml. Note that the name of the planner is global_planner/GlobalPlanner the same specified in global_planner_plugin.xml. Now, you are ready to use your new planner'** I tested whether it worked by running: **'roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch'** and then I tried running: **'roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch map_file:=$HOME/map.yaml'** which led to the error I showed above. I have created the map-yaml, so there's no misunderstanding whether that's missing.

I would be very glad for any help, thank you ^^

Edit: My system only had 'navfn' on it, not 'global_planner' or 'carrot_planner', if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

After looking over the code I found a solution. It doesn't make everything work perfectly yet, but seems to solve the immediate problem.

The problem was that in my 'global_planner_plugin.xml' I just used the code provided in the tutorial:

```
 <library path="lib/libglobal_planner_lib">
  <class name="global_planner/GlobalPlanner" type="global_planner::GlobalPlanner" base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">
    <description>This is a global planner plugin by iroboapp project.</description>
  </class>
 </library>
```

But in the `carrot_planner.cpp` file it says:
`PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(carrot_planner::CarrotPlanner, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)`

Changing `type="global_planner::GlobalPlanner` to `type="carrot_planner::CarrotPlanner` and then launching turtlebot3 doesn't give the same error anymore.